# Find the least value of '$n$' such that no factorial has $n$ trailing zeroes, ($n+1$) trailing zeroes and ($n+2$) trailing zeroes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find the least value of '$n$' such that no factorial has $n$ trailing zeroes, ($n+1$) trailing zeroes and ($n+2$) trailing zeroes

I only know that trailing zeroes depends on the power of $5$ and $2$. Since $5$ power is always more than $2$ hence, it only depends on $5$.

Comment: Hint: So you need to find $k$ such that $k!$ has at least four more trailing zeroes that $(k-1)!$ has.

Comment: How k! will have 4 more trailing zeroes than (k-1)!? How 11! can have 4 more trailing zeroes than 10!. On dividing 10 by 2 and 5 and on dividing 11 by 2 and 5 gives me the same power of 5 @HenningMakholm

Comment: Well, $10000!$ definitely has four more trailing zeroes than $9999!$. (This isn't the smallest example, though.)